# Is "voluminous" more commonly used to describe women's (not men's) hair?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage

Is the word *voluminous* more commonly used to describe women's hair? What's the male counterpart?

Actually I'm not very sure about my statement. But judging from [Google Images](https://www.google.com/search?q=voluminous%20hair&psj=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&biw=1366&bih=682&bvm=pv.xjs.s.en_US.c75bKy5EQ0A.O&um=1&ie=UTF-8&hl=en&tbm=isch&source=og&sa=N&tab=wi&ei=1PjsUdCTKYKkkAWCo4F4). It seems like it is more commonly used to describe women's hair.

What's the male counterpart of the word?

Comment: ‘Voluminous’ in itself isn’t particularly feminine to me, it’s just that not many men have the kind of hairdo that I would describe as voluminous, whereas quite a lot of women do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For men it's more common to say: natural *[**thick**](https://www.google.com/search?q=voluminous%20hair&psj=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&biw=1366&bih=682&bvm=pv.xjs.s.en_US.c75bKy5EQ0A.O&um=1&ie=UTF-8&hl=en&tbm=isch&source=og&sa=N&tab=wi&ei=1PjsUdCTKYKkkAWCo4F4#um=1&hl=en&tbm=isch&sa=1&q=thick+hair+men&oq=thick+hair+men&gs_l=img.12..0l6j0i5l4.15448.17298.2.19474.6.6.0.0.0.0.205.832.2j3j1.6.0....0...1c.1.21.img.XIPfC3Rfff4&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.49478099,d.ZWU&fp=438bffece8e24e00&biw=1366&bih=613)* wavy hair. You can omit the adjectives; natural and wavy, but that is how I would describe the male *counterpart*.

[image: thick wavy hairstyle]

Comment: There’s more to voluminous hair than it just being thick and wavy, though (and it doesn’t have to be natural at all, of course). I would say the young man in the photo you used as an example has _voluminous_ hair, too—or, more colloquially, simply that he has _big_ hair. I have thick and wavy hair, but it’s not particularly voluminous, more helmet-like.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Wavy and curly hair gives a voluminous look. Dead straight hair can of course be thick but it rarely achieves that "bouncy" look.

Comment: I would rather say that wavy and curly hair **aids** a voluminous look. As I said, my hair is both thing and wavy, but not voluminous. Straight hair is not usually voluminous, but I still think it makes more sense to simply use ‘voluminous’ for both men and women equally to describe that particular look.

Comment: You can equally describe women's hair as being thick and wavy. In the link janoChen posted many would fit that description. Voluminous, however, does tend to be collocated with women hair. I don't know why. Probably due to hairspray ads in the 70's when that look was very fashionable. Think, "Charlie Angels" the TV series and Jaclyn Smith.

Comment: Exactly—I would describe most of the models in janoChen’s link as having thick and wavy, voluminous hair. And as I said above, I think the collocation between the word ‘voluminous’ and women is simply from the collocation between voluminous hair styles and women. Not many men _have_ hair that you’d really describe as voluminous—especially because ‘voluminous’ is quite a positive word, and it is rare that such a hairstyle is desirable for men, for social reasons. Instead, if they do have such hair, it is often an annoyance and we say they have ‘big’ hair instead (which is a more negative word).

Comment: True. But big hair also has positive connotations. Lank thin hair is never desirable :)

Comment: (Did I really just vacillate between ‘hairstyle’ and ‘hair style’ _in the same comment_? Oh dear …)